# Python condition in function without_E not working correctly

Tags: python

Somehow the `without_E` function is not working. I'm getting the whole list back. But I'm only expecting to detect the words with the letter `'e'`. Also, when I print the list, I get the words in the form of `[words]` instead of just `"words"`. Is this normal behavior? The functions are reading from a `wordlist` file.

```
# Display words without letter "e"
def without_E(word):
    for ch in word:
        if ch == 'e' or ch == 'E':
            print "here" * 5
            return False
    return True


def percentage_words():
    i = 0
    j = 0
    fin = open("wordlist")
    for line in fin:
        i += 1
        word = line.split()
        if without_E(word):
            j += 1
            # print word
    percentage = (j * 100) / i
    print percentage


def main():
    # word_list()
    # long_words20()
    # without_E()
    percentage_words()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
word = line.split()
```

This line will give all the words in the line as list of strings and you are passing that to `without_E`. So, you are actually checking if the individual words are either `e` or `E`. Instead of that, you can do something like this

```
i, j = 0, 0
with open("wordlist") as fin:
    for line in fin:
        i += 1
        for word in line.split():
            if "e" not in word.lower():
                j += 1
```

Now, `for word in line.split()` will iterate through each and every word in the current line and then we check if `e` is *not* there in the lowercased version of the `word`.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to red your file object so if you just have words in your file change `fin = open("wordlist")` with `fin = open("wordlist").readlines()` . But if you have lines in your file you need to `split` your line and then check :

```
def percentage_words():
    i = 0
    j = 0
    fin = open("wordlist").readlines()
    for line in fin:
      for word in line.split():
        i += 1
        word = line.split()
        if without_E(word):
            j += 1
```

Also instead of your `without_E(word)` function an `for` loop you can use `in` operation :

```
def without_E(word):
        if 'e' in word or 'E' in word:
            print "here" * 5
            return False
    return True
```